# How to increase the count of ML training units (25 by default) on Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

There is a limit for ML training units on Google cloud platform. [By default](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas), it is 25. I need to increase up to 100. As you may know, to use scale-tier PREMIUM_1 you need to have at least 75 ML Units.

> Concurrent number of ML training units: 25.

How can I increase the count of ML training units?

Comment: How long ago did you create your project?

Comment: I have created a project yesterday  (1 day ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request for more ML unit quota (as well as other quota) by following the steps described here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas#requesting_a_quota_increase

The most direct link is: [Cloud Machine Learning Engine Quota Request form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1f-tmYYl8uiV6KcWFLsNKwWnTvk4KwQYsCzZHcb3g2YM/viewform)

Comment: there is no other options except you have mentioned. I accept this answer nevertheless I could not get more ML units after trying both requests. I have switched to AWS and happy )